# Redactor air not visible when code mirror is enabled

Tags: redactor

I'm using Redactor 2 and I set config `air: true` and `plugin: ['codemirror']`.
The issue is when I click on html button the air toolbar disappears and is not possible to have toolbar on redactor again.

Is there a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick solution to show toolbar when hover code mirror

```
 callbacks: {   
   init: function() {    
   $('.CodeMirror-scroll').on('hover',function(){
         $('.redactor-air').css('display','block');       
          });
       } 
}
```

But the issue is the same when i have more then one redactor in same page, because it shows both toolbar...

Any help on this ?
Thanks

Comment: Try changing $('.redactor-air') to $(this).closest('.redactor-air') inside the hover event callback function.

Answer (score 1):

The right thing to do is

```
var that = this;
var id = $(that.$editor).attr('id')
$('#'+id).parent('.redactor-box').find('.CodeMirrorscroll').on('hover',function(){
var idnumber = id.replace('redactor-uuid-','')
$('#redactor-air-'+idnumber).css('display','block');
});
```

on

```
init: function()
                {
```

Now its ok, its only opens one if you have more than one

THanks
Carlos Vieira

Answer (score 1):

I created a callback on click in the .CodeMirror-gutters:

```
init: function(e) {
    var a = this.codemirror;
    $('.CodeMirror-gutters').on('click',function(e){
        if(a.$textarea.hasClass('open')){ a.hide(); }
    });
},
```

and added a Material Icons code icon to the .CodeMirror-gutters:after css:

```
.CodeMirror-gutters:after {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    etc...
    content: '\E86F';
}
```

so that when the user clicks the gutter in 'source' mode, it toggles back to 'visual' mode.